# How to call SeedRoles method in Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to build an authorization system (role-based authorization) for my app.

I have seed roles class but I don't know the right way to call the seed method in `Program.cs` to run every time when the app runs like this code :

```
using login_and_registration.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace login_and_registration.Models
{
    public class SeedRoles
    {

        public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var context = serviceProvider.GetService<lAppregistrationContext>();

            string[] roles = new string[] { "Owner", "Administrator", "Tests2", "Editor", "Buyer", "Business", "Seller", "Subscriber" };

            foreach (string role in roles)
            {
                var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);

                if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
                {
                    roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
                }
            }

            context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "role-based" part is usually the **authorization** (*what can I do?*) - not the "authentication" (who am I?)

Comment: first change context.SaveChangesAsync(); to context.SaveChanges(); then u will either get errors wor healp u think aboy what u doing ... also  roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role)); to  roleStore.Create(new IdentityRole(role)); if you dont know how to use Async dnt until it makes sense

Comment: also remove `ASP.NET Core 6` from the title as its both incorrect and irrelevant.

Comment: @marc_s   
I wrote it by mistake, I have corrected it, thanks for alerting me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SeedRoles` class should be a **static** class, you can modify it as below:

```
//required
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
//using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
public static class SeedRoles
{
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()))
        {
            string[] roles = new string[] { "Owner", "Administrator", "Tests2", "Editor", "Buyer", "Business", "Seller", "Subscriber" };

            var newrolelist = new List<IdentityRole>();
            foreach (string role in roles)
            {  
                if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
                {
                    newrolelist.Add(new IdentityRole(role));
                }
            }
            context.Roles.AddRange(newrolelist);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: In my application, the DB context is `ApplicationDbContext`, you can chnage it to yours.

Then, in the program.cs file, you can call the seed role method after the `var app = builder.Build();` line, code like this:

```
// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()    //enable Identity Role
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>() ;
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    SeedRoles.Initialize(services);
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

More detail information, you can check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc/sample/6.0-completed/Program.cs).

Comment: it works , thanks